# Get information of all open QGIS projects

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have build a QGIS Plugin which uses a layer with vector tiles (with an attribute location created with `gdaltindex`) as input to create raster files (slope, hillshades, ...) derived from a DEM for a distinct area. When I choose tiles from another area of interest I remove all raster files first. Logically I can't do this when another QGIS project is open which includes on of these raster layers. In my case I have two projects: an "online" (including network drives) and an "offline" project. With the plugin you have the possibility to update one project with the new created raster layer of the other project via a `.qlr` file.

So when I want to remove the raster files, there is the error: `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: (file-name)`

I have solved this using:

```
try:
    filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(raster_dest_data, "*.*"))
    for f in filelist:
        os.remove(f)
except:
    QMessageBox.warning(iface.mainWindow(),'Information', u'Quit all other QGIS projects')
    return False
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Is there the possibility to get information about other open QGIS projects with pyqgis?

I was thinking about a message: `There are 2 more QGIS projects open. Please quit QGIS "Project_1" and QGIS "Project_2" first to proceed!`

Answer (score 1):

I tried some things during the last hours and found a solution:

**EDITED***-simplified code

```
import os
import subprocess
from os.path import basename
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

# Hiding subprocess window
SW_HIDE = 0
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

# Redirect stdin and stderr to NUL.
try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL
except ImportError:
    DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)

# get output from tasklist (-v verbose; tasklist output with window title)
res = subprocess.check_output('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq qgis-bin.exe" -v 2>NUL', stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, startupinfo = info)

# title of current project where the python code is running
recent_project =os.path.splitext(basename(QgsProject.instance().fileName()))[0]

qgis_procs = []
qgis_list = ['QGIS', 'qgis', 'Qgis']

# creating list of open qgis window titles, except the one where the code is running
for i in res.split('\r\n'):
    if any(word in i for word in qgis_list) and not recent_project in i:
        qgis_procs.append(i.split()[-1]) 

prj_count = len(qgis_procs)
if prj_count > 0:
    if prj_count == 1:
        prj_word1 = 'is'
        prj_word2 = 'project'
    if prj_count > 1:
        prj_word1 = 'are'
        prj_word2 = 'projects'
    QMessageBox.warning(iface.mainWindow(),'Information', u'There ' + prj_word1 + ' ' + str(prj_count) + ' more QGIS ' + prj_word2 + ' open. Please quit the ' + prj_word2 + ' %s' % ' and '.join(map(str, qgis_procs)) + ' to proceed.')
else:
    pass
```

You can paste this code into your QGIS python console.

For example: When I have 3 QGIS projects open.
[image]

Any suggestions on how to grep information better from the `tasklist` output are welcome.

**UPDATE**

For Linux:

```
import os
import subprocess
from os.path import basename
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL
except ImportError:
    DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)

res = subprocess.check_output(['xwininfo', '-tree', '-root'], stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)

all_procs = None
all_procs = res.split("\n")
qgis_procs_temp = []

for i in all_procs:
    if "QGIS" in i and "qgis.bin" in i:
        qgis_procs_temp.append(i.split('"')[1].split('-')[1].split())

qgis_procs = [item for sublist in qgis_procs_temp for item in sublist]
prj_count = len(qgis_procs)
base=basename(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
recent_project =[os.path.splitext(base)[0]]
diff_list = [item for item in qgis_procs if item not in recent_project]

if prj_count > 1:
    if prj_count == 2:
        prj_word1 = 'is'
        prj_word2 = 'project'
    if prj_count > 2:
        prj_word1 = 'are'
        prj_word2 = 'projects'
    QMessageBox.warning(iface.mainWindow(),'Information', u'There ' + prj_word1 + ' ' + str(prj_count-1) + ' more QGIS ' + prj_word2 + ' open. Please quit the following ' + prj_word2 + ':' + ' %s' % ' and '.join(map(str, diff_list)) + ' to proceed.')
else:
    pass
```